# Evaluate $\sqrt{2^{2014} + 2^{2011} + 2^{2006}} \pmod{17}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Evaluate:

$$I = \sqrt{2^{2014} + 2^{2011} + 2^{2006}} \pmod{17}$$

$$I = \sqrt{2^{2006}\cdot (1 + 2^{5} + 2^{8}  )} \pmod{17} = 2^{1003} \cdot \sqrt{2^8 + 2^5 + 1} \pmod{17}$$

The answer is $0$ somehow, how should I do this?

Comment: $$2^8+2^5+1 = 2^8+2\cdot 2^4+1 = (2^4+1)^2 = 17^2.$$

Comment: Now that I think about it. $2^8 = 256 + 32 + 1 = 289 = 17^2$ then $I = 2^{1003} \cdot 17 \pmod{17}$ Because it is divisible by $17$, $J \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$

Comment: You can post your answer on your own question.